# What does lockstep mean in programming?

Tags: java, collections

I have been reading `Effective Java` on

> Item 46: Prefer for-each loops to traditional for loops

In the part where are mentioned the cases when is iterator/for loop needed isntead of for-each loop, there is this point:

> Parallel iteration—If you need to traverse multiple collections in
>   parallel, then you need explicit control over the iterator or index
>   variable, so that all iterators or index variables can be advanced
>   in lockstep.

Now, I understand what explicit control over iterator/index variable mean (not controller by for each loop). But I could not understand the meaning of lockstep in this sense. I tried to google it and found an article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockstep_%28computing%29) which states:

> Lockstep systems are fault-tolerant computer systems that run the same
>   set of operations at the same time in parallel.

This I understand as having aditional instance of for example server for fail-over That's ok. But I fail to fully understand what could be the exact meaning in the context of iterating over collection in programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this context, the meaning is more like the [military marching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockstep).

Or, when one operation advances, other operations advances/follows with it.

Or more specifically, if you want to iterate over two collections, you cannot easily the foreach construct:

```
for (Item i : list1) { //only allows you to iterate over 1 list.

}
```

Iterate over 2 collections )

```
Iterator iter1 = list1.iterator();
Iterator iter2 = list2.iterator();
while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()){
    Item a = iter1.next();
    Item b = iter2.next();
    doSomething(a, b);
}
```

i.e. while iterating list1, iterating list2 follows with it - "in lockstep"

Comment: This answer seems to be incorrect, because there is no parallel execution in the code. The code is purely serial. `iter1.next()` and `iter2.next()` are not happening simultaneously! Lockstep means they must happen on different processors at the same time.

Comment: @Sourabh Applied to programming, lockstep doesn't necessarily imply parallel execution - although synchronized threads that run in a lockstep fashion in relation to each other is another common pattern described by the word lockstep, it's not the only pattern where this is used.

Comment: Well, I do not think that lockstep "applied to programming" means something different. Lockstep execution is basically related to processor. It means that all the processors are fetching the instruction and operands at the same time, and executing the same instruction at the "same time". The "same time" literally means at the same clock cycle from the optimization point of view. In addition, if the program is "serial" then there is no way that one statement (`iter.next()`) will advance in front of the other, in such a case why should it be called lockstep?

Answer (score 8):

The meaning of "lockstep" in this context is not special, but is the English-language meaning, interpreted as "at the same time".

Answer (score 7):

Lockstep execution means that the same statement will be executed on all the processors at the same time "in parallel". This is of special importance when you are dealing with GPGPU (General Purpose Graphics Processing Unit) programming. GPU's actually do the exact same operation in parallel on a different data set.

Example: In a for loop with independent operations on data (say a vector addition problem), all the processors may call the add operation simultaneously, then assignment operation simultaneously on two separate vector index, in a lockstep fashion, as one addition and assignment is independent from another.

Answer (score 0):

Here, it just means that the index and iterator are advanced at the same time, so that they always correspond to the same element.  Kind of like two people walking side-by-side--they have to step forward together if they're to remain side-by-side.