# Does Lockstep in SIMD/SIMT imply the error tolerance?

Tags: multithreading, error-handling, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have found one [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260322/what-does-lockstep-mean-in-programming/22260574#22260574), it seems that "lockstep" in GPU means "independent parallel".

But in [the wikipedia about SPMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_program,_multiple_data#SPMD_vs_SIMD), it related [this page about lockstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockstep_(computing)) to SIMD which says:

> The redundancy (duplication) allows **error detection and error correction**: the output from lockstep operations can be compared to determine if there has been a fault if there are at least two systems (dual modular redundancy), and the error can be automatically corrected if there are at least three systems (triple modular redundancy), via majority **vote**.

Q:Then does SIMD lockstep imply ECC? In the GPU context, it seems to split data and scatter them to different threads in parallel, no ECC is implied.

Comment: "the output from lockstep operations *can* be compared"   If they actually are or not obviously depends on the implementation.   Do not assume ECC is present because you are running lockstep.

Comment: The two definitions of "lockstep" are not really the same. The former applies in algorithm/computing and is rather general. The later mainly applies in fault-tolerant systems (only). GPUs can be fault-tolerant systems, but they are generally not (at least, by default). Thus, no ECC is mandatory. Actually the Wikipedia page has a bias on fault-tolerant system and requires a bit of hindsight. In fact, the page mention "This article needs additional citations for verification". You need to be very careful when you read this.